# How to return the correct value when Divide and Conquer Algorithm(for 1-D Closest Pairs) has done its job?

Tags: c++, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I need to find the closest pair of numbers of an integer array. For example: If I have {25, 13, 59, 7, 16} numbers, my result should be |13 - 16| = 3. So I try to solve the problem using Divide and Conquer Algorithm. But when I get differences of numbers from sub-problems, I can't store and compare them. I see where my program goes wrong when I debug it but couldn't find any solution for hours.

Here is my function:

```
int closestPairs(int list[], int first, int last)
{
    if (last - first == 1)
        return 0;
    else if (last - first == 2)
        return abs(list[first] - list[last - 1]);

    int median = (first + last) / 2;

    int left = closestPairs(list, first, median);
    int right = closestPairs(list, median, last);

    int temp = abs(list[first] - list[last - 1]);

    if (abs(left - right) < temp)
        temp = abs(left - right);

    return temp;
}
```

And here is the driver function:

```
int main()
{
    int list[] = { 34, 23, 48 , 4, 66, 69};
    int n = sizeof(list) / sizeof(int);
    cout << closestPairs(list, 0, n) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So how can I store the value obtained from abs(left - right) and see if it's less or greater than the next value? Or am I wrong all over and doing everything wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: I will be very appreciated if you can specify why it is incorrect. I am stuck at this problem for hours and my brain is about to explode. :)

Comment: Do you have to do this using Divide and Conquer Algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I can do it using an iterative algorithm but in this case I need to use Recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the concepts of using recursion to find the solution and storing a value for comparison to the next iteration are opposing concepts in this case. Storing a variable for comparison in a recursive function seems like it would be a bit of a mess (and require some significant restructuring of your code). The idea as I understand it of your divide and conquer algorithm is to take a big list of ints and divide it into smaller lists and allowing the best possible answer to make its way up through the chain. Here's the way I see this working based on your code (using mostly pseudo code):

```
int FindClosest(int list[],int first,int last)
{
     if(number of elements in list == 2)
     {
         return (int2 - int1)
     }
     if(number of elements in list == 3){
     {
         if((int3-int2)<(int2 - int2))
             return (int3-int2)
         else
             return (int2-int1)
     }
     if(number of elements in list >3)
     {
         subList1 = oneSubGroupofElements(list)
         subList2 = anotherSubGroupofelements(list)
         if(FindClosest(subList1)<FindClosest(subList2))
              return Findclosest(subList1)
         else
              return FindClosest(subList2)
     }
}
```

There is another issue with this method which you can see for lists with more than 2 elements, that is because your result relies on pairwise neighbours, you must consider that you can't just split the list in half. For example:

```
int list[] = {1,4,5,9}
```

would cause problems if you simply split the list into two lists of two elements as the difference between 4 and 5 would not be considered (which would be the correct answer). Your sublists would have to include the overlap so that at least one of the sublists returns 5-4 when called from FindClosest.

Answer (score -1):

You have to sort the list before finding the closest pair using the divide and conquer technique. Because that eliminates many corner cases.

Comment: I have changed the list manually to sorted form but still the result is incorrect. The problem begins when temp is defined but couldn't figure out why and what the solution is, naturally.

Comment: Yeah well you don't need the "temp" you just need to return the smallest of "right" and "left". Moreover, in your stopping conditions, you should handle the case if last==first and return INT_MAX for that (defined in the header climits). Also, for the case last-first ==1, you should return the distance as INT_MAX instead of 0).